# Extracting HID from Windows INF File

Tags: windows, inf, hardware-id

I am trying to parse a large number of INF files for Windows driver installations.

I have a large collection of drivers for various devices (Biometrics, Bluetooth, Video, etc) -- all with varying creation dates and contents.
I am trying to parse these files such that I can input the file contents and return the [Hardware ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hardware-ids) which is formatted like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/standard-usb-identifiers) for USB devices, and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/identifiers-for-pci-devices) for PCI and PCI-E devices.

My issue is that there does not seem to be any specific order or standardization for the location of these values in the respective INF file.

For example, this Bluetooth driver from Intel begins as follows:

```
[Version]
Signature   = "$WINDOWS NT$"
Class       = Bluetooth
ClassGuid   = {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}
Provider    = %PROVIDER_NAME%
CatalogFile = ibtusb.cat
DriverVer = 07/06/2018,20.70.1.1

[SourceDisksNames]
1=%SOURCEDISK1%,,,

[SourceDisksFiles]
ibtusb.sys      = 1
ibtfw.dat = 1

[DestinationDirs]
ibtusb.Copy         = 12        ; drivers
firmware.Copy       = 12

;
; Driver Information
;
[Manufacturer]
%COMPANY_NAME% = Device,NTamd64.10.0...16299

[Device.NTamd64.10.0...16299]
;---Start VID_PIDS section---
%iBT_USB% = ibtusb, USB\VID_8087&PID_0025&REV_0001
%iBT_USB% = ibtusb, USB\VID_8087&PID_0025&REV_0002
;---End VID_PIDS section---
```

Notice how the devices ID (`USB\VID_8087&PID_0025`) is stored under the `[Device.NTamd64.10.0...16299]` key.

On this particular line: `%COMPANY_NAME% = Device,NTamd64.10.0...16299`

The device ID is set equal to `%COMPANY_NAME%` and is separated by `itbtusb,`

However, if I compare this layout with a Nokia Bluetooth driver, for example, it is totally different:

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=CustomUSBDevices
ClassGuid={a503e2d3-a031-49dc-b684-c99085dbfe92}
Provider=%Manufacturer%
CatalogFile=%DriverBaseName%.cat
DriverVer=05/15/2012,2.4.0.4

[ClassInstall32]
AddReg=ClassInstall_AddReg

[ClassInstall_AddReg]
HKR,,,,%DeviceManagerCategory%
HKR,,Icon,,"-20"

[Manufacturer]
%Manufacturer%=DeviceList, NTamd64

[ControlFlags]
ExcludeFromSelect=*

[DeviceList]
%NokiaBH907%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_0421&PID_064B
%NokiaBH907%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_0421&PID_064C

[DeviceList.NTamd64]
%NokiaBH907%=DriverInstallX64, USB\VID_0421&PID_064B
%NokiaBH907%=DriverInstallX64, USB\VID_0421&PID_064C
```

This time, the device ID is stored under the `[DeviceList]` and `[DeviceList.NTamd64]` keys.

```
[DeviceList]
%NokiaBH907%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_0421&PID_064B
%NokiaBH907%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_0421&PID_064C

[DeviceList.NTamd64]
%NokiaBH907%=DriverInstallX64, USB\VID_0421&PID_064B
%NokiaBH907%=DriverInstallX64, USB\VID_0421&PID_064C
```

With this I had some general questions:

- Is there any fool-proof methods for extracting this?
- I've realized that the key names for the data containing the hardware ID can be found in the `[Manufacturer]` key -- is this always the case?
- Is the device ID *always* the second value? (separated by a comma)
- Does Microsoft document/define/recommend this behavior for vendors?

If clarification needed, please suggest an edit or leave a comment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to consume the output of the [`InfVerif`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/running-infverif-from-the-command-line) utility that comes as part of the [Windows Driver Kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk). You don't need to have Visual Studio or anything else installed to use it.

It takes an `/info` flag that prints device information in a consistent format. For example, running it on a random inf file on my current machine:

```
xusb22.inf Information

INF Hash:       e41db3fe2103ee21
Family ID:      Microsoft-xusb22.inf

Device:         Xbox 360 Controller for Windows
Hardware ID:    USB\Vid_045E&Pid_028E
Service:        xusb22
Section Name:   CC_Install
Architecture:   amd64

Device:         Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows
Hardware ID:    USB\Vid_045E&Pid_0719
Service:        xusb22
Section Name:   CC_Install
Architecture:   amd64

Device:         Xbox 360 Controller for Windows
Hardware ID:    USB\MS_COMP_XUSB10
Service:        xusb22
Section Name:   CC_Install
Architecture:   amd64

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some MSDN links that you might find useful:

[INF Manufacturer Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-manufacturer-section)

[INF Models Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-models-section)

[Looking at an INF File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/looking-at-an-inf-file)

[General Syntax Rules for INF Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/general-syntax-rules-for-inf-files)

The sections you're looking for are called *Models* sections, which indeed are defined in the *Manufacturer* sections - this is mentioned in the *Models* section documentation from the link above:

> Each models-section-name must be listed in the INF Manufacturer
>   section of the INF file. There can be one or more entries in any
>   per-manufacturer Models section, depending on how many devices (and
>   drivers) the INF file installs for a particular manufacturer.

Here's the documented *Models* section syntax (from the same link):

```
[models-section-name] |
[models-section-name.TargetOSVersion]  (Windows XP and later versions of Windows)

device-description=install-section-name[,hw-id][,compatible-id...]
[device-description=install-section-name[,hw-id][,compatible-id]...] ...
```

If you want to parse the INFs by hand, you might also find useful some of the Windows SetupAPI utilities, listed here:

[Extracting File Information from the INF file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/setupapi/extracting-file-information-from-the-inf-file)

If you are interested in extracting info relevant only for a specific OS version, these APIs might also be of use:

[SetupDiGetActualModelsSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetactualmodelssectionw)

[SetupDiGetActualSectionToInstallEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetactualsectiontoinstallexw)

Finally, if you're just interested in the hardware IDs, using the **InfVerif** WDK tool `/info` flag mentioned by @cody might indeed be the best way to solve your problem, since the tool will do all the necessary parsing for you.

Comment: Incredibly useful, however InfVerif seems to do exactly what I need :)